# Silverstripe 3.3 to 4.0 manifest couldn't parse

Tags: php, upgrade, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

After upgrading silverstripe 3.3 to silverstripe 4.0 I get this error. If I comment the line of the error a same error with a different php script appears. After some research I havent find a working solution. I already tried to /dev/build and /?flush=1 and /?flush=all but the error appears also trying.

> Fatal error: Couldn\'t parse D:\xampp\htdocs\test4/cms/silverstripe-assets/src/AssetControlExtension.php when building config static manifest in D:\xampp\htdocs\test4\framework\core\manifest\ConfigStaticManifest.php on line 247

It is the following function:

```
protected function isVersioned()
{
    return class_exists(Versioned::class) && $this->owner->has_extension(Versioned::class);
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: what version of PHP did you run composer? Does this match to the version you run on the machine? Did you install via composer or did you use the download?

Comment: I use php 7.2.2 and the project was version 3.3 of silverstripe and updated it via composer.json to 4 and then run composer update

Comment: I think this is probably too broad. The problem could be caused by any of your project's code or third party modules you're using (that aren't updated with composer perhaps), and without seeing everything it's pretty hard to say what's causing this